# Debugging BIRT ODA Driver in Eclipse SDK - NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: eclipse, debugging, eclipse-plugin, birt

All,

I am not too sure if this is a BIRT/Eclipse SDK/Developer problem...

We are in the process of looking into BIRT for Eclipse SDK (Indigo).  We have invested in the book Integrating and Extending BIRT by Jason Weathersby et al.  It takes you through the process of creating your first ODA Driver which is essentially an 2 plug-in projects:  ODA Driver and ODA Driver UI.  Unfortunately it never talks about debugging in any detail.

The idea is for the ODA Driver to interface to our application to retrieve the data.  I have added and External JAR reference for our applications JAR file to the ODA Driver project from Properties->Java Build Path.  This appears under the Referenced Libraries in the Eclipse workspace.  All the referenced JARs that our application uses are also displayed under the Referenced Libraries.

As things have not been working which I will explain shortly, I have also created a HelloWorldX java project in the Eclipse SDK workspace which has a single class called HelloThere with a single static method which is:

```
public static String getIt() 
{
    return "Ding Dong";
}
```

I have added this as a project reference to the ODA Driver project from Properties->Java Build Path.

So what I have done...

**Create Projects**

I have created the 2 projects in my Eclipse SDK IDE.  The ODA Driver contains a reference to our legacy application JAR file which we call in code.

This now also calls the HelloWorldX project.

**Begin Debugging Session**

I have added a breakpoint in Connection#open.  This breakpoint is on the first line.

I start the debugging session by clicking on the debug toolbar item.  First time it prompts me I selected run as Eclipse Application.  This fires up a new session of Eclipse SDK which I can load up the report designer file from File->Open...

The report loads into the Eclipse SDK IDE as follows:

[image: BIRT Report Eclipse]

I create a new Data Source by right-clicking on Data Sources and selecting New Data Source.  From the New Data Source dialog, I select the name of my ODA Driver and click on Next.  This displays a dialog with a Test Connection button.

I click on the Test Connection button which hits the breakpoint in the Connection#open.

When I step over the following code I get the NoClassDefFoundError thrown.

```
System.out.println(HelloThere.getIt());
```

The exception is also thrown when I make a call to any of our legacy code in the external JAR file I have referenced.  Eclipse displays a window in the workspace for OdaConnection.open(Properties) line: 267 which has Source not found and a button with Edit Source Lookup Path...  I have tried different combinations for setting the source path for our application.  Clicking on the button will bring up the following dialog:

[image: Edit Source Lookup Path]

In a nutshell the stack trace is as follows:

```
org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.OdaException ;
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: HelloWorld/HelloThere
        at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.profile.OdaConnectionWrapper.open(OdaConnectionWrapper.java:215)
        at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.profile.OdaConnectionWrapper.<init>(OdaConnectionWrapper.java:59)

... (some trace omitted as big!)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: HelloWorld.HelloThere
      at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:513)
      at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
      at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
      at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
      ... 49 more
```

I am new to Eclipse so please be gentle.  Can anyone tell me where to look or any other information I should post.  I might be doing things totally wrong but surely not the first person who would want to debug a BIRT ODA Driver.  I have looked all over the internet to find a solution for this.  The only post I found that was relevant was on the Eclipse forums which never got an answer back in 2007!!!  [See Eclipse Community Forums](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/msg/75272/235051/#msg_235051)

**EDIT**

I have put some code to output the classpath from my ODA Driver using System.getProperty("java.class.path",".");

D:\Software\Eclipse\eclipse-SDK-3.7-win32\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar

**END EDIT**

Thanks

Andez

Answer (score 2):

Having tried all kinds of solutions, I finally cracked it.

Having followed the Integrating and Extending BIRT CSV ODA Driver example, I noticed there was a Hibernate Driver.  You can download the source from [Actuate Site](http://www.actuate.com/products/resources/?articleid=11719).

This driver was put together differently.  It had settings for manipulating the class path when creating it through the wizard.  Unfortunately the class path could not be set in the version of Eclipse SDK I downloaded - Indigo.  So I thought I would go through manually and see the differences.

To do this you only need to open the MANIFEST.MF in the Eclipse IDE.

**build.properties tab**

Include all jar files you want to reference/include as follows:

```
source.odasentinel.jar = src/
output.odasentinel.jar = bin/
bin.includes = plugin.xml,\
           META-INF/,\
           odasentinel.jar,\
           lib/activation.jar\
```

...

**MANIFEST.MF tab**

Set the Bundle-ClassPath setting to include all jar files you want to reference/include as follows:

```
Bundle-ClassPath: odasentinel.jar,
 lib/activation.jar,
 lib/bsh-2.0b2.jar,
 lib/comm.jar,
```

You can now run and debug your ODA Driver with Eclipse.